# Does the limit exist if the values are different?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I got 
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \ln\left(\frac{1+{y^2}}{{x^2} +xy}\right) $$

and I get

- $\lim =  0,$ when $y = 0,$
- $\lim = 0,$ when $y = x,$

but when $y = -x$ I get undefined. So the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: do you mean $\log\frac{1+y^2}{x^2+xy}$?

Comment: yes  that is what i meant

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/).

Comment: Then .. just insert (1,0) into your expression. There is no reason for a limit-calculation.

Comment: why? shouldn't i calculate the limit?

Comment: What for? $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)} \ln\left(\frac{1+y^2}{x^2+xy}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{1+0^2}{1^2+1\cdot 0}\right) = \ln(1) = 0$

Comment: to make sure the limit always give the same value no matter the direction and thus exist

Comment: The only interesting limit you could calculate are those, where $(x,y)$ goes to some point with $x^*=-y^*$. In all other cases you can calculate the value of ln() directly.

Comment: i don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @question the fact that all limits in directions exist doesn't mean that the limit exists! Consider a set $\{(x,y):(|x|-1)^2+y^2<1\}\cup\{(x,y):x=0\}$ and the characteristic function of this set. Then the linear "cuts" of this function going through $(0,0)$ are all continous at this point, but the function itself is not continuous!

Comment: if they have all the same values it exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get straight about *what* is approaching *what*:

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \ln\left(\frac{1+{y^2}}{{x^2} +xy}\right) $$

means you need to take the limit of the *point* $(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ as $(x, y)$ approaches the point $(1, 0)$, i.e. as both $x\to 1$ AND $y \to 0$.

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \ln\left(\frac{1+{y^2}}{{x^2} +xy}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{1 + 0^2}{1^2 + 1\cdot 0}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{1}\right) = \ln 1 = 0$$.

So no worries.

Comment: ah yeah y=-x it should have been y=-x+1

Comment: i get ln(1/2) when y = x-1

Comment: yeah when i do the hospital rule it gives me 1/2

Comment: nah how come i get ln(1/2) when y = x-1 and 0 when y = 0?

Comment: i need to approach (1,0) from all direction and get the same value, but i don't, so it musn't exist, right?

Comment: when y = x-1 = 0, x = 1

Comment: i know, but i don't get ln(1) when i do the hospital rule after substituting y by x-1.

Comment: You are not taking the limit $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \left(\frac{1+{y^2}}{{x^2} +xy}\right)$. You are taking the limit $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \ln\left(\frac{1+{y^2}}{{x^2} +xy}\right)$. l'hospital is not needed, nor appropriate here.

Comment: why? so you just replace x by 1?

Comment: Yes, just replace x by 1, and y by 0.

Comment: thank you, can you tell me in 1 short sentence why the hospital rule isn't appropriate though?

Comment: @question Read l'Hopital's rule.  It only applies when the limit of the top and bottom are both 0 or both infinity.  We don't have either in this case so it doesn't apply.  We don't even have the limit of a fraction.  You have the limit of the natural log of a fraction, which is not the same thing.

Comment: question: @Graphth answered your question as best as I could.